# Giving different attribute value to not connected polylines using ArcGIS Pro or ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I have 33245 not connected/not touched polylines in 5 rows (with Z value).

How do I merge all polylines which is in one line (more close to each other) to give them attribut value?

Result should be 5 merged rows (let's say X1, X2, X3, X4, X5) with different attribute (from 1 to 5). Not need to connect lines.

Is there are some ready ArcGIS functions or do you have algorithm tips for python?

I am beginner user of Python.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) module providing 3d distance between end points of the same group lines is smaller than distance to other group points.

This is workflow:

```
arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management("sparts_3d", "C:/SCRATCH/ends_3d.shp","BOTH_ENDS")
arcpy.Near3D_3d("ends_3d", "ends_3d")
arcpy.AddField_management("ends_3d", "TO_LINE", "LONG")
```

[image]

Picture above shows my own tool. It can be replaced by a)clone point b)join using fields show in the picture c)calculate field TO_LINE using field calculator.

Your table should look exactly like this:
[image]

Script below is using highlighted fields as FROM and TO nodes to create undirected   graph and compute connected components. Highlighted row shows point that exceeds 3d distance threshold, because it sits at the very end of line (there are 10 of them).

So

```
arcpy.AddField_management("ends_3d", "PART_NO", "SHORT")
```

and run this from mxd:

```
import arcpy
import networkx as nx
# define 3d distance threshold
q='"NEAR_DIST3" < 1.0'
tbl=arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray("ends_3d",["ORIG_FID","TO_LINE"],q)
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(tbl)
dictFeatures = {}
for m,item in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G)):
    for i in item:dictFeatures[i]=m
# data transfer
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("ends_3d",("ORIG_FID","PART_NO")) as cursor:
    for fid,prt in cursor:cursor.updateRow((fid,dictFeatures[fid]+1))
```

It will populate PART_NO field in points table. Use relevant joins to transfer this info to parent lines:

[image]
[image]