# Selecting mainstream lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop

[image]

I have a line layer with segment lines, some of them mean a mainstream system that I'd like to keep. Others are isolated from the mainstream which I'd like to delete.

The mainstream is made up by splines, each line segment is connected to another line segment. The issue here is that I don't have any attribute/field that can be used to divide them.

I tried "select by location" to select the ones have common ending points, but that only delete part of the isolated segments. Because some of the isolated segments are connected by several lines.

Then I tried making a buffer of the lines, but "dissolve" never worked for me.

Is there a way to unite all connected lines to one?

Then I can select my mainstream by a single click.

---

1. 'Polyline to raster' to create a raster.
2. 'Region group', set neighbor number as 8, pixel size as 100 (very small)
3. Use a color ramp to check on the new region group raster.

[image]

But now I am lost.

How can I extract the mainstream part from this raster?

The attribute table looks like this:

Sort by Count

[image]

Sort by Value

[image]

Comment: See vector solution here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353486/giving-different-attribute-value-to-not-connected-polylines-arcgis-pro-python/353518#353518 alternatively convert lines to raster and do region group, 8 neighbors to find connected groups.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for answering! Now I am half-way there. Please see my updated post. I think I can only add more pictures in the original post.

Comment: There are different options. I guess you need a group with largest COUNT. You might extract it by attributes and expand by 1 cell. If you convert output to polygon, it is your buffer for main stream. See if this works.